# GitLab CI secret variables for Gradle publish

Tags: gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gradlew

How to setup Gradle publish task user credentials with GitLab CI secret variables? I am using [gradle maven publish plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html), and here is snippet from build.gradle

```
repositories {
    maven {
      credentials {
        username artifactUser
        password artifactPass
      }
      url "..."
    }
  }
```

I've tried to use `gradle.properties` as below

```
artifactUser=${env.MAVEN_REPO_USER}
artifactPass=${env.MAVEN_REPO_PASS}
```

And several ways of accessing secret variables in `.gitlab-ci.yml` file (because gradle.properties is not picked up from gradle or variables are not transformed correctly, it is in root project dir)

Method 1

```
'./gradlew publish -x test -PartifactUser=${env.MAVEN_REPO_USER} -PartifactPass=${env.MAVEN_REPO_PASS}'
```

Error: `/bin/bash: line 56: -PartifactUser=${env.MAVEN_REPO_USER}: bad substitution`

Method 2

```
    before_script:
      - chmod +x ./gradlew
      - export REPO_USER=${env.MAVEN_REPO_USER}
      - export REPO_PASS=${env.MAVEN_REPO_PASS}
    ...
    deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ./gradlew publish -x test -PartifactUser=$REPO_USER -PartifactPass=$REPO_PASS
```

I am using `openjdk:8-jdk-slim` image for build using gradle wrapper. Seems like there are several [issues](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27098) with this kind of variable usage, do we have any workaround?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need `env.` prefinx in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`. You don't need to re-export the variables as well.

If you have defined a variables named `MAVEN_REPO_USER` and `MAVEN_REPO_PASS` in Gitlab CI/CD settings for the project, you can just use them in Gradle script:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username System.getenv("MAVEN_REPO_USER")
            password System.getenv("MAVEN_REPO_PASS")
        }
        url "…"
    }
}
```

Comment: if I defined a variable named VERSION in my Gitlab CI/CD could I access it in my gradle.properties? or can they only be accessed in my Gradle script?

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I resolved it (unfortunately the official GitLab doco is very focused on Maven... :(

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0.9'


task zipSource(type: Zip) {
    from file('files/test.zip')
    archiveClassifier = 'testZip'
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'GitLab' 
            url 'https://gitlab.my-company.com/api/v4/projects/2302/packages/maven'
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
                name = "Job-Token"
                value = System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN")
            }
            authentication {
                header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
            }
        }
   }
   publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId = 'project1-sample'
            //deploy jar vom Java
            from components.java
            //deploy arbitrary Zip file
            artifact zipSource
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful.  I modified this to support my use case:   
`name = "${System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN") ? 'Job-Token' : 'Private-Token'}"`
`value = "${System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN") ?: gitLabPrivateToken}"`
This allow for both gitLabPrivateToken in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties locally, as well as CI builds without additional gradle command line builds.

Answer (score 2):

As md_rasler mentioned in his comment above, his code worked almost perfectly. I had to modify it slightly and use  different name 'Deploy-Token' as the default value for the name. My config lookks like this:

```
maven {
    url "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<<project_id>>/packages/maven"
    credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
        name = "${System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN") ? 'a -Token' : 'Deploy-Token'}"
        value = "${System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN") ?: gitlabDeployToken}"
    }
    authentication {
        header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use environment variables directly to set gradle properties, see full documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html?_ga=2.159637757.1965154025.1534419796-23381218.1520942598#sec:project_properties).

in your case set `artifactUser` and `artifactPass` as env variables (best as secrect ones).